# Yield CSV row as list of complex list comprehension with if statements

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension

I am trying to yield each row of CSV as list of `int`, `float`, `str` respectively while using list comprehension with if statements.

How do I write a list comprehension with if statements that will convert each element of CSV row into `int`, `float`, `str` respectively ?

Problem: float created as string.

```py
import csv

FILE = "file.csv"

def all_values(file):
    with open(file, "r") as file_open:
        reader = csv.reader(file_open)
        for row in reader:
            yield [
                    int(x)
                    if x.isnumeric() else float(x)
                    if x.isdecimal() else x
                    for x in row
            ]

values = [x for x in all_values(FILE)]

print(values)
```

Problem in part of code:

```py
            yield [
                    int(x)
                    if x.isnumeric() else float(x)
                    if x.isdecimal() else x
                    for x in row
            ]
```

File:

```
100,"Jin",10.56
200,"Tonic",15.99
300,"Vodka",20.39
```

Output:

```
[[100, 'Jin', '10.56'], [200, 'Tonic', '15.99'], [300, 'Vodka', '20.39']]
```

Wrong type of values:

`'10.56'`, `'15.99'`, `'20.39'`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The `isdecimal()` method call isn't doing what you want because `'10.56'.isdecimal()` returns `False` (because the period '.' is not a decimal character). It therefore goes to the final else which gives it as is i.e. a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `isdecimal()` is returning `False` because `.` is not considered a decimal character. Instead you could change your code to be:

```py
yield [
    int(x)
    if x.isnumeric() else float(x)
    if x.replace('.','',1).isdigit() else x
    for x in row
]
```

In this case the order of the checks matter, int must be first.

Comment: nice, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to make it a bit safer if its a float or not:

```
def is_float(element) -> bool:
    try:
        float(element)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def all_values(file):
    with open(file, "r") as file_open:
        reader = csv.reader(file_open)
        for row in reader:
            yield [
                    int(x)
                    if x.isnumeric() else float(x)
                    if is_float(x) else x
                    for x in row
            ]
```

Comment: the handler is not necessary here, because of 3 types variable. And it can be handled with if statements.

Comment: The sequence of if statements will handle it, as mentioned in @ChrisOram answer